# Gcd and harmonic sequence

Tags: arithmetic

Consider  the harmonic sequence
$$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} $$
Set $$H_n = \frac{a_n}{n!}$$

> Prove that $\gcd(a_n;n!)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Your conjecture is wrong from $n=4$ and onward.

Observe that

$$H_{4}=\frac{25}{12}$$

that is $a_{4}=50 \implies \gcd(a_4,4!)=\gcd(50,24)=2$